# Get all relationship data in one request with Directus 8 JS SDK

Tags: javascript, directus

I have the following collections: `Movies` and `Actors`.

I just want to call `client.getItems('Movies')` and get the data of all `movies` with the linked `actors` data per item also. It seems to me I can only do that, if I call another `client.getItems` with the specific ID of the actor:

```js
client.getItems(
  'actors',
  {
    filters: {
      movie: {
        movie_id: 5
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Is there no other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After chatting with the awesome folks of Directus (https://directus.chat/), I was able to solve my problem. You just have to use a field query: https://docs.directus.io/api/query/fields.html

For example:

```js
client.getItems(
  'movies',
  {
    fields: ['*','actors.*.*']
  }
)
```

This will give you all `movies` with all data and all relational `actors`.